# Wordpress function PHP echo inside echo?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the translation of a link anchor for WPML translator - for the word "Next":

```
function getPrevNext(){
    $pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
    $pages = array();
    foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
       $pages[] += $page->ID;
    }

    $current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $pages);
    $prevID = $pages[$current-1];
    $nextID = $pages[$current+1];

    echo '<div class="prev-next-page-bottom-navigation">';

    if (!empty($prevID)) {
        echo '<div class="prevpage-bottom-navi">';
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_permalink($prevID);
        echo '"';
        echo 'title="';
        echo get_the_title($prevID); 
        echo'">Previous</a>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
    if (!empty($nextID)) {
        echo '<div class="nextpage-bottom-navi">';
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_permalink($nextID);
        echo '"';
        echo 'title="';
        echo get_the_title($nextID); 
        echo'">Next</a>';
        echo "</div>";      
    }
}
```

I need to change the following line of `echo'">Next</a>';` to be:

```
<?php echo __('Next','my_wp_theme');?>
```

echo inside echo makes a PHP error

**SOLUTION:**

Change `echo'">Next</a>';` with `echo'">'.__('Next','my_wp_theme').'</a>';`

Comment: Try this echo '">'.__('Next','my_wp_theme').'</a>';

Comment: Your second line should work fine.

Comment: @twelvell No problem, you can't really nest the echo function inside PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can write all of this in a better way to read and to print it like you wanted.

```
<?php if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
<div class="alignright">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">
        <?php _e('Next','my_wp_theme'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this a better solution than the original way? I picked mine from WP codex

Comment: No problem you can use the same principles for the `prevID` and don't forget to close the container div `.prev-next-page-bottom-navigation`

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify this with sprintf

```
echo sprintf('<div class="alignright"><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></div>', get_permalink($nextID), get_the_title($nextID), __('Next','my_wp_theme'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a wp theme function which lets you navigate through child pages : updated post